# Contour Deformation in the Laplace Inversion Formula

Tags: laplace-transform, contour-integration, analytic-functions, analytic-continuation

Following Szpankowski - Average Case Analysis of Algorithms on Sequences the exponential generating function of $g(n)$ which is thought to be analytic in $n$ is defined as
$$
G(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} g(n) \, \frac{z^n}{n!}
$$
and can be written as a Laplace Inversion Integral
$$
G(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\delta-i\infty}^{\delta+i\infty} g^{*}(s) \, \exp\left(ze^{s}\right) \, {\rm d}s
$$
where $\delta >0$ and $g^{*}(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $g(n)$.

Szpankowski now claims that the line of integration can be replaced by some contour ${\cal L}_\epsilon$ which is defined by
$$
y={\rm sgn}(y)\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta\right)(x-\epsilon) \tag{1}
$$
where $\theta,\epsilon$ I think (he is using $\theta$ in the context of a linear cone opening around the x-axis with angle $\theta<\pi/2$) are just parameters here and $z=x+iy$.

He also supplies a plot[image: Laplace Contour Deformation] of the image of ${\cal L}_{\epsilon}$ for the specific case $\epsilon=0.1$ and says that its parametrization reads
$$
e^{-|t|/2+\epsilon}
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(t) \\ \sin(t)
\end{pmatrix} \qquad t\in (-\infty,\infty) \, .
$$
Even though I can not relate this plot or parametrization to (1) in any way, I am also confused about how this contour arises from the original one.

Hoping for input.

Comment: How is the complex integral you wrote an Inverse Laplace Transform?

Comment: Are you talking about the fact the there is a factor $e^{ze^{s}}$ in the integrand and not $e^{zs}$ ?

Comment: yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Write $g(n)$ as an inverse Laplace transform, interchange integral and summation order and carry out the sum.